# how to use laravel illuminate in a custom project

Tags: laravel, ioc-container, lumen, illuminate-container

I have a static site with a lot of pages. Now I got a new requirement. Client need a Client Area, I am thinking to use laravel Database Eloquent, Session, Form/html, Session and want to use them as alias like use in laravel/lumen. The problem is that I want static pages same as it is with .html extension, is there any solution? I want some packages with aliases to speed up.

I spent a complete day on Configuring Input and Eloquent but I wasn't able to setup to other packages. But I don't know how to set aliases and service providers. Any idea?

Specific:
I need Laravel Some packages

1. Session,
2. FileSystem
3. Mail
4. Input
5. Database
6. Html/Form,
7. Validation

I don't need others packages and need aliases same as laravel used in (config/app)

Comment: Your question is very wide, try to ask specific questions.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use lumen for your client area. If you don't want to touch static pages serve them as they are using a rewrite rule on your web server.

Comment: can i get a rewrite code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can use laravel components outside laravel project please read the article : http://www.richardbagshaw.co.uk/using-illuminate-components/